# Copula - Correlation Help

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, copula, t-distribution

I need some help with copula.

I am using the copula with either the multinormal or the student t kernel. I thought before that when I input in my correlation matrix, if I simulate enough random variates, and then take the correlation of those random variates, the resulting correlation matrix would converge to my input. This was not the case.

I am now informed that I need to adjust my correlation matrix before input to arrive at my target correlation matrix.

Can anybody share some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

While I have yet to find the reason why, I think you need to perform a Cholesky-decomposition to your correlation matrix. The chol(X) function in R should do the trick, where X is your correlation matrix.

Bear in mind, I think I also read somewhere that if your correlation matrix is not positive definite the output of Cholesky-decomposition may not be unique. You can check using the function is.positive.definite(X) from the [matrixcalc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixcalc/index.html) package.

Source: [page 19](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/fima/publikationen/TSchmidt_Copulas.pdf)